# HERE SDK - Raster layers are not transparent

Tags: here-api

I am using the Navigate Edition of HERE SDK for Android. I am adding custom raster layers and two of my layers are transparent (Lite Edition showed the layers correctly), but the MapView shows these layers with a white background instead of transparent. This is bad as the white background hides the underlying map. Am I missing something to have the transparent layer?

Here's my code:

```
    private RasterDataSource createRasterDataSource() {
    List<Integer> storageLevels = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);
    RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Provider rasterProviderConfig = new RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Provider(
            mTemplateUrl,
            TilingScheme.QUAD_TREE_MERCATOR,
            storageLevels);
    String path = "cache/raster/toner";
    long maxDiskSizeInBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 32;
    RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Cache cacheConfig = new RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Cache(path, maxDiskSizeInBytes);
    return new RasterDataSource(mMapView.getMapContext(),
            new RasterDataSourceConfiguration(mName, rasterProviderConfig, cacheConfig));
}

private MapLayer createMapLayer() {
    MapLayerPriority priority = new MapLayerPriorityBuilder()
            .renderedAfterLayer("ocm_cartography")
            .build();
    MapLayerVisibilityRange range = new MapLayerVisibilityRange(0, 22 + 1);
    try {
        MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayerBuilder()
                .forMap(mMapView.getHereMap()) // mandatory parameter
                .withName(mName + "Layer") // mandatory parameter
                .withDataSource(mName, mMapContentType)
                .withPriority(priority)
                .withVisibilityRange(range)
                .build();
        return mapLayer;
    } catch (MapLayerBuilder.InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The mMapContentType is MapContentType.RASTER_IMAGE

Answer (score 1):

Got support from HERE team (thanks!) and for transparent layers I had to set the hasAlphaChannel for the RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Provider:

```
RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Provider rasterProviderConfig = new RasterDataSourceConfiguration.Provider(
            url,
            TilingScheme.QUAD_TREE_MERCATOR,
            storageLevels);
rasterProviderConfig.hasAlphaChannel = true;
```